# Scroll issue When I move to another tab

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a playlist page where i create my custom tabs. Tabs working very well but the problem is that when i scroll down first tab content and then move to another tab then scroll position remain same, i am not able to see the content of second tab.

And I don't want to use **default tabs** of ionic.

Here is plnkr link where i implement my code:-

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlists" class="tabSection">
<div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-dark tabs-color-energized">
  <div class="tabs">
  <a class="tab-item" ng-click="articles(false)">
    Home
  </a>
  <a class="tab-item" ng-click="categories(true)">
    Favorites
  </a>
</div>
</div>
  <ion-content>
  <div class="articleSection" ng-hide="showme">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
        {{playlist.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
 </div>
 <div class="categorySection" ng-show="showme">
     <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in favorites" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
        {{playlist.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
 </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nlUgR8?p=preview

Any Suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  $ionicScrollDelegate.

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope,$ionicScrollDelegate) {

  $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();

});
```

This will show scroll content from top.

Hope it works for you.